# remove chapterprecis from content table

Tags: memoir

I am using chapterprecis to write a small summary for each chapter in memoir document class. However, I just noticed that in contents table, it shows the whole text of this chapterprecis. I am wondering how to get rid of it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{companion}
\setlength\prechapterprecisshift{20pt}

\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\renewcommand\colorchapnum{\color{ared}}
\renewcommand\colorchaptitle{\color{ared}}
\chapterstyle{pedersen}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is a test.}
\chapterprecis{
This is a test to show that the chapterprecis shows in the contents table and I would like to know how to get rid of this.}
\section{section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{section 2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\chapterprecishere` will not add the text to the table of contents. The corresponding command to only add the text to the toc is `\chapterprecistoc`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{companion}
\setlength\prechapterprecisshift{20pt}

\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\renewcommand\colorchapnum{\color{ared}}
\renewcommand\colorchaptitle{\color{ared}}
\chapterstyle{pedersen}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is a test.}
\chapterprecishere{
This is a test to show that the chapterprecis shows in the contents table and I would like to know how to get rid of this.}
\section{section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{section 2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]